# Get the last set of dates in each year in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that has the following form:

```
ranking_date  ranking  player_id  ranking_points
------------  -------  --------- ---------------
1980-12-22    3        100284     0
1980-12-22    21       100676     0
1980-12-22    44       100653     0
1980-12-22    136      100713     0
1980-12-22    182      100757     0
1980-12-22    211      100800     0
1980-12-22    255      101061     0
1980-12-22    283      101062     0
1980-12-22    372      100837     0
1980-12-22    390      100682     0
1980-12-22    423      100923     0
1980-12-22    440      100936     0
1983-01-03    2        100284     0
1983-01-03    7        101062     0
1983-01-03    9        100676     0
```

So I would like to get the last ranking_date for each year. I have rankings from 1973 to 2016, but not all the last rankings are in December. Also this current table is little over 1 million rows so I'm doing this to get the year end rankings. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your _work/code_?

Comment: All your ranking which are in 1980-12-22, which one is the last ranking? Do you mean last ranking for each player in each year?

Comment: This is just a sample. The real table has like a million rows. It basically has  a rank for a like 1000 players from every week for 40 years. I'm trying to get the last set of rankings for the each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to list the ranking records for the last date of each year. I'm calling your table `tablename`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE ranking_date IN (SELECT MAX(ranking_date) 
                       FROM tablename 
                       GROUP BY YEAR(ranking_date))
```

The subquery

`SELECT Max(ranking_date) FROM tablename GROUP BY YEAR(ranking_date)` will identify the last (maximum or `MAX`) calendar date of each year. The years are identified with the `YEAR(ranking_date)` grouping.  Applying that subquery to the `WHERE` clause in the main query should pull the records for the last date of each year.

Comment: Yep! Thanks so much. I knew I needed some combination of max, but I didn't think to use a sub query.